# Minkowski sums of sets

Tags: real-analysis

> The Minkowski sum of two sets $A,B$ is defined: $A+B=\{a+b:a\in A,b\in B\}$

Is it valid, for the singletons $\{1/n^2\}$, the minkowski sum

$\sum$$\{1/n^2\}$$=\{\pi^2/6\}$ ,$n\in \mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: You've only defined a binary operation. Now you have to define what it means for a limit of a sequence of sets to converge to a set, and I think you'll have a tricky time doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you use the [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance) to define the topology on subsets of the real line so you can think about the limit of the partial sums, each of which is a set.

I'm curious: why do you want to do this?

Comment: to see if the minkowski sum is valid for an infinite number of sets.

Comment: @Ethan But Hausdorff metric is not a metric except on the compact subsets of a metric space, so this is going to be problematic for defining infinite sums of even compact subsets of Minkowski metrics.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Fair enough. In this case everything is in the unit interval so I think it's OK. The OP can worry about more general applications.